# Not Redrawing CRectTracker in Activex

Tags: mfc, activex

I created an ActiveX Project using MFC.

CRectTracker class was created.

Then I drew a class using the OnPaint function.
However, the screen is not updated.

I painted using the OnDraw function.
However, afterimages remain.

How can you solve it?

[Problem Picture...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlgkw.png)

This Code is...

```
CArray <CRectTracker, CRectTracker&> m_arrRect;

void CWebBrowserCtrl::AddArea()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    CRect rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    CRectTracker tracker;
    tracker.m_rect = rect;
    tracker.m_nStyle = 0;
    tracker.m_nStyle |= CRectTracker::dottedLine;
    tracker.m_nStyle |= CRectTracker::resizeOutside;

    m_arrRect.Add(tracker);

    this->Invalidate();
}


void CWebBrowserCtrl::OnDraw(CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& /* rcInvalid */)
{
    if (!pdc)
        return;

    int length = m_arrRect.GetCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        CRectTracker tracker = m_arrRect.GetAt(i);
        if ((tracker.m_rect.Width() > 0) && (tracker.m_rect.Height() > 0))
        {
            tracker.Draw(pdc);
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
void CThermalViewForWebBrowserCtrl::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    int length = m_arrRect.GetCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        CRectTracker tracker = m_arrRect.GetAt(i);
        if ((tracker.m_rect.Width() > 0) && (tracker.m_rect.Height() > 0))
        {
            tracker.Draw(&dc);
        }
    }

    COleControl::OnPaint(&dc);
}
```

Comment: Did you override OnEraseBackground()? What that returns determines whether or not the control will clear the background before OnPaint(). So either set it up so that the control erases itself correctly, or do it yourself by essentially doing DrawRect() of the whole client rect before you draw the rect tracker (you can also do a smaller area, but then you have to keep track of the previous rectangle in OnMouseMove). This might cause flicker, for which you'd have to use CMemDC or something similar (essentially, implement double buffering).

Comment: no, i'm not overriding OnEraseBackground()

Comment: Well then have you tried overriding it? Look at COleControl - its OnEraseBackground() implementation explicitly says 'do nothing - controls erase their background in their OnDraw'. So, either do your own erasing in OnDraw, or override OnEraseBackground.